# How does battle mechanism of game work?

Tags: algorithm, game-engine

As i proceed towards the end of my gaming project. I am stuck at a part that is commonly known as **Battle Mechanism**.

### What is Battle Mechanism?

Battle mechanism is the algorithm which decides what will be the end result of the battle (how many troops died and how many of them survived).

**Note:-** Keeping in mind that all the troops are of same type and attribute

### Factors that affect the results

Health
Attack
Defense
Speed

### For Example #1

Team 1 | Team 2
1           | 1

**Possible result**
any one team can win this because both have same no. of troops

### For Example #2

Team 1 | Team 2
20         | 100

**Possible result**
in this **team 1 will lose all their troops** on the other hand **team 2 wins** but also loses some troops (troops of team 2 died would be less than 20 because as compared to team 1 they had more troops)

### Problem I am facing

I don't have a clue what kind of algorithm to use to achieve such kind of results. 
I would appreciate if someone can suggest me a way to solve this or provide me a link that explains how to construct this algorithm.

Comment: SQL-Server game engine?

Comment: @ForguesR The UI is bad, but the rest should be ok ,-)

Comment: Well.. if teams have equal strenghts/sizes then the result is either random or draw?

Comment: @ForguesR all the data is saved and manupilated in the SQL server itself and can you explain the insert query you just wrote

Comment: @KubaWyrostek in the first case it is random but in the second case how to calculate how many troops will die of team 2 (which has greater troops in number)

Comment: @DeveloperNation that would depend on if the game mechanics had a variable that increased attack/defense when in numbers and(or) in greater numbers than the other team. Also what % of that benefit and how it would scale with higher numbers of troops AND a higher percentage of troops

Comment: Possible easy solution `Example 1`: fairness to all players that can be 100% draw or just add a 5-10% random luck. `Example 2`: team1--> 0 troops left; team2 --> (100-(100/20))+- random (5-10)%

Comment: @Matt you are on the correct track but in the initial stage i would like to know how the strength affects the result then i would integrate attck, defense, speed etc.

Comment: @DeveloperNation My comment was based on the troops and teams having identical attributes and features apart from the number of troops

Comment: @nada can you explain what is that 5-10% you are talking about? or can anyone provide me with a link that explains a battle simulator of any game?

Comment: @DeveloperNation Its your game! You should come up with your own mechanics to make it unique and if your uniqueness is good enough people will want to play it. No one wants to play a rehash of another game thats been done a million times that just looks different.

Comment: @Matt i wanted to know how to walk before i run that is why i posted the question.

Comment: @DeveloperNation im not saying come up with the code/algorithm now, i'm saying come up with your own mechanics, in plain English, then convert to code.

Comment: @Matt please if you can find a link that explains the mechanism please feel free to post it. Till then i will try thinking to create my own mechanism.

Comment: @DeveloperNation Your missing the point here completely however if you include in your question what attributes your troops/teams/whatever can have (what you have decided already) like strength speed health etc etc then someone can come up with some basic mechanics you can work from

Comment: This is NOT a forum question. This is off topic for two reasons. It is entirely too big of a response AND it is going to be primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about  something like this..
Each army has 2 values Attack/Defense they can be calculated from your 4 values

- `Attack = (your)attack * speed`
- `Health = (your)Health * defense`

these number basically refer to the ability of army to deal damage(Attack) and the amount of damage they can sustain(Health);

then you keep dealing ones damage to the others health util one reaches 0

1. `army1 (400/1000) vs army2 (600/1000)`
2. after first round
3. `army1 (400/400) vs army2 (600/600)`
4. no one defeated go for another round
5. `army1 (400/-200) vs army2 (600/200)`

this will mean that army2 survived with 200 health..

to figure out how many soldiers survived you can do simple percentage..
if it started with 1000 health and was reduced to 200 it mean only 20% survived
so if the army had 50 soldiers only 10 (20%) remain..

can you make this work?

Comment: this would be a good start for me and would change some variables according to me. Thanks man for your help and time